# upload_max_size doesn't change

Tags: uploads, media

I need to increase the max size for media.
I've change my php.ini.
I've change my .htaccess
I've change my functions.php

And it's not working.

I've directly change (for try & test) the wp-include/media.php file like this :

```
function wp_max_upload_size() {

    @ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
    @ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
    $u_bytes = wp_convert_hr_to_bytes( ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' ) );
    $p_bytes = wp_convert_hr_to_bytes( ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) );

    if(isset($_GET['mathieu'])) {
        var_dump($u_bytes);
        var_dump($p_bytes);
    }
    return apply_filters( 'upload_size_limit', min( $u_bytes, $p_bytes ), $u_bytes, $p_bytes );
}
```

In the backoffice, I see :

[image]

I've no idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've find the problem. It's multisite WP. The settings need to be set in the multisite admin panel.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen